# Overriding my Edit to the original, but not rolling back?

Tags: discussion, editing

I edited [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188418/could-my-sableye-beat-shuckle) today, and then someone proposed an edit that reverted it (basically) back to the original. I have no idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You and he both started your edits at the same time. Unfortunately, since you submitted yours first, that meant that his edits undid all your edits. I believe the other user got a warning, which he chose to ignore, telling him this would happen.

On this particular question, the point is moot, since it is closed and will soon be deleted.

Comment: True. TBH I was the one that proposed to reject the edit, not because it undid mine, but because I saw it as basically the same as the original editing...